# Line breaks not showing up properly

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to have spacing show up between a paragraph and heading in the following excerpt:

In my [article](http://theuniversityblog.co.uk/2010/09/21/clubs-societies-zen/) [series](http://blog.sysil.com/2010/09/21/extracurricular-club-handling-sovereign-zen-style-part-2/) on handling extracurriculars, I coined the term Sovereign Zen philosophies. It builds off of Cal Newport’s [Zen Valedictorian philosophy](http://calnewport.com/blog/2008/04/18/how-to-become-a-zen-valedictorian-decreasing-your-stress-without-decreasing-your-ambition/). Before you criticize this article as being a copycat, there are some subtle differences between both philosophies, namely the self-protective critical thinking components, and their applicability beyond schooling career.

## Definition

**Zen Valedictorian:** A way of living to become less overloaded and less stressed without becoming less impressive

However, the line break between career and definition isn't showing up properly even with two `<br`>`<br`>. How would you suggest dealing with this?Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presentation layer is best handled by CSS. In this case that would probably be `margin-bottom` rule for your heading.

Markup with `<br />` is usually unreliable. WP mostly relies on `<p></p>` tags for paragraphs and not line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use it but I think this: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/wiki/TextControl might help. Also see: http://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=linebreaks+get+removed+by+wordpress

Also try:

```
<p align="none"> </p>
```

or see: http://www.orphicpixel.com/common-wordpress-annoyance/ (which simply means: install the tinymce editor advanced and change some settings)