# Why is WordPress WYSIWYMG and how do I make it WYSIWYG?

Tags: editor, html, formatting

WordPress may have a text editor that appears to be WYSIWYG, but upon using it I discovered that it is actually WYSIWYMG- What You See Is What You *Might* Get (once it's done screwing with the HTML).

Isn't there a way to tell it to **do nothing** with the text you put into it? Just leave it as it is. No optimizations, no trying to guess what I meant, no correcting my HTML, no converting whitespace into nbsp's that for some reason cause line breaks, no changing the formatting or the spacing between embedded objects after you edit it to fix one typo...

I did try searching the settings area but found only one HTML related option (regarding matching closing tags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you post your content, WordPress will pass **the_content()** function through a number of filtering function's. There are four of them, wptexturize(), convert_smilies(), convert_chars(), and wpautop(). All of these are defined in wp-includes/formatting.php and are referenced in wp-includes/default-filters.php.

To remove these filtering functions you can disable them by putting this in your functions.php theme file:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_smilies');
remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
```

That should remove all formatting between what you save in TinyMCE (the WYSIWYG editor) and the front end view of your website. For more reference on what each of these does refer to the codex.

I hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: How do I access that file?

Comment: If you mean the functions.php file you can do it 2 ways: FTP into your WordPress site and browse to "wp-content/themes/{theme-name}/functions.php". Open and edit that file. Another way is using the Theme editor in WordPress, which is at http://my.wordpresssite.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php. From there opne the "Theme Functions" file and add the code there.

Comment: Also, be cautious when removing these filters. They can cause some issues with output but also do wonders for formatting content. For more info refer to this article in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/How_WordPress_Processes_Post_Content

Comment: Thanks! 8) was showing up as a smilie with sunglasses - very frustrating.

Comment: Actually, better to turn off smilies from Dashboard - Settings / Writing as the link you provided suggests.

Answer (score 0):

for adding php some php plugins exist...and additional plugins that make the plugins work via e.g. WYSIWYG posting via the XMLRPC interface... and if you really get desperate in a wp mu environment, you can always put your content in by reading a database record, replacing the content and rewriting the record to the external database... (e.g. if in the revision structure someone with more rights initially created the record (see comments on http://bluesome.net/post/2005/08/18/50/))

See also this question: [Line breaks not showing up properly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/line-breaks-not-showing-up-properly/3475#3475)